# Using Terraform and creating lambda module, how to set default env variables and add custom ones if required

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

I'm trying to create a custom Terraform AWS lambda module that will have a set of default environment variables in all lambdas, while allowing the option through a variable to add custom env variables to a specific lambda? I'm currently doing something like this, but I'm not sure how to / if it's possible to implement this?

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
  function_name    = "..."
  filename         = "..."
  handler          = "..."

  dynamic "environment" {
    for_each = length(keys(var.environment_variables)) == 0 ? [] : [true]
    content {
      variables = var.environment_variables
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [merge function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/merge) of Terraform to merge the two maps to one before assigning them to the Lambda:

```
locals {
  default_environment_variables = { default_key = "default_value"}
  all_environment_variables = merge(local.default_environment_variables, var.environment_variables)
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
  function_name    = "..."
  filename         = "..."
  handler          = "..."

  environment {
    variables = local.all_environment_variables
  }
}
```

Two notes:

- Since `var.environment_variables` is given as second argument to `merge`, its values have priority if both maps contain the same key, i.e., you can overwrite the default environment variables by resetting them in `var.environment_variables`.
- If you have always set default environment variables, you don't need the trick with `for_each`.